# Running C code without rooting

Tags: android

Can I run a c program which I cross compiled in my android phone without rooting it? I thought that I could use only API provided by Google ie Java only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to user1203673's answer, you can download the NDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), it comes with example code.

Using the NDK doesn't require root access and, although not recommended by google, can be used entirely without java.

Answer (score 0):

using android ndk u can generate .so file and can make use of the methods that are mentioned in C program